# Conversion to local time zone yields different value in different machine

Tags: python, datetime, mongodb, pymongo

I am storing few tweets in mongodb in UTC format and converting utc time specified in tweets to local time zone in my local machine it renders correctly in local machine but not in my server.

### Storing

```
        #d is the tweet

        created_at = d['created_at']
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at,\
                 "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
        dt = dt.replace(second = 0, minute=0)
        db.collection({'created_at': dt})
```

### Conversion

```
here = tz.tzlocal('Asia/Colombo')
utc = tz.gettz('UTC')
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    ist = item['created_at'].replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(here)
    ist_readable = ist.replace(minute =0, second = 0).ctime()
    items[index]['created_at'] = ist_readable
return items
```

### Output

`Thu Apr 19 04:00:00 2012

    Thu Apr 19 03:00:00 2012`

### Output in Local Machine

```
Thu Apr 19 09:00:00 2012 
Thu Apr 19 08:00:00 2012
```

Local machine time zone is set to 'IST', server time zone is set to 'UTC'.

Answer (score 0):

```
here = tz.gettz('Asia/Colombo')
```